# How to strip internal CSS tags but not inline css tags in incoming email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I want to parse the incoming emails but at the time of sanitize i want to remove the internal styling, but i want to keep the inline styling also. with the nokogiri it removes the style tags from all file .

```
parsed_html = Nokogiri::HTML(raw_html)
parsed_html.css('style').remove
```

I expect to remove the extra internal style tags and content inside but not to remove the inline styling

Comment: That shouldn't strip inline CSS, but you're saying it does. Can you expand on this example?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SanitizeHelper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize). You can custom remove tags or style as your expect.

Example tested in the Rails console:

```
html = "<p id="text_header" style="display:none;">asdasd</p>"
ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(html, attributes: %w(id))
```

It will return:

```
=> "<p id=\"text_header\">asdasd</p>"
```

Comment: Rather than toss out a link please explain how it works. Educate, don't just hand out code.

Comment: in rails dock explain detail how to use and config to his project. if you want some code i will show you in my update

Answer (score -1):

adding whitelist attributes will allow the style tags with attributes but will remove the tags of style from file which can be responsible for xss/xsstc. Adding src and alt because this class and style also removing the img tag which i dont want to remove so if you add src alt attributes in this white list it will allow the img attributes also.

```
sanitize(parsed_html.to_s, attributes: %w(src alt class style)
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're trying to explain. Please reread it and, if necessary, ask for help with the language.